# Log4J not found in classpath

Tags: java

My package model is that i have two war files in a EAR and all the common jars are placed in the EAR/lib directory.

I am using apache fop jar for printing some output into PDF format. Now when i try to print the output i get the exception below

`

```
    ]] Root cause of ServletException.
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Category
        at org.apache.avalon.framework.logger.Log4JLogger.info(Log4JLogger.java:73)
        at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.startDocument(FOTreeBuilder.java:239)
                                                                                                  om.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToSAXHandler.startDocumentInternal(ToSAXHandler.java:95)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.SerializerBase.startDocument(SerializerBase.java:1216)
        at GregorSamsa.transform()
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Category
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:280)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:253)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:177)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace`
```

Not sure why its happening since the fop.jar is part of a specific war and i tried placing the log4j.jar in the specfici war as well but to no help.

Comment: Maybe there is another log4j implementation used by your servlent engine which does not have this method?

Comment: Its in the classpath as are all the other jars.

Comment: Yes but what if your _app server_ has a version of it which takes precedence over yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make it work finally.

Actually fop.jar has a dependency on avalonXX.jar which was not part of the war but part of the common jar folder in the ear. I moved the jar file into the war lib directory and VOILA...Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it to be a classloader issue. Although you have not specified the appliction server you are using, but no matter which one, you need to make sure the jar is available for the class loader, which is loading your application. Check the settings for class loader of your ear and associated policy.

Comment: I am using weblogic server. Can you be more specific how to check the classloader setting and the policy

Comment: @sidshu Can you try to put log4j jar in  $DOMAIN_DIR/lib?

Comment: came close , it works that way but now the issue is the logs for the two wars are going into a single log file.

Comment: I had separate log4j.jar in each war file because otherwise all the logs starts appending into a single log file. Thats what is happening here as well.

Comment: @sidshu This is just a workaround but if you want to use it then you can define the package level log appender in log4j and can redirect the outputs in different log files for them